# Strange URI characters "%f0%9f%8c %b4%f0%9f%9a %8c%f0%9f%90"

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, character, uri

I was trying to figure out what was the characters encoded in this url:
http://whatyouth.com/9236/roadtripppp-%f0%9f%8c-%b4%f0%9f%9a-%8c%f0%9f%90-roadtrip-throwback-again-sorry-missingsummer-palmtrees-rememberwhatyouth/

When I use the javascript function `decodeURI`, I got this error :

```
decodeURI("http://whatyouth.com/9236/roadtripppp-%f0%9f%8c-%b4%f0%9f%9a-%8c%f0%9f%90-roadtrip-throwback-again-sorry-missingsummer-palmtrees-rememberwhatyouth/")
> URIError: URI malformed
```

Does someone know what these characters are ?

- `%f0%9f%8c`
- `%b4%f0%9f%9a`
- `%8c%f0%9f%90`

Comment: Those encoded bytes are not in UTF-8, it may be some other encoding. No idea which one it is though.

Comment: another strange thing with this : try this : `var url = 'http://whatyouth.com/9236/roadtripppp-%f0%9f%8c-%b4%f0%9f%9a-%8c%f0%9f%90-roadtrip-throwback-again-sorry-missingsummer-palmtrees-rememberwhatyouth/'; console.log(url);` => bug in chrome console.

Comment: I don't have Chrome. What does it do?

Comment: a weird bug, nothing shows up and the console becomes buggy

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that is a Windows-1252 encoding : [ASCII Encoding Reference (W3Schools)](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) (Sorry for that W3Schools link... not my favourite website)

I replaced every '%' with '\x' in my url and I used functions in this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4129920/3484498

```
var url = 'http://whatyouth.com/9236/roadtripppp-\xf0\x9f\x8c-\xb4\xf0\x9f\x9a-\x8c\xf0\x9f\x90-roadt‌​rip-throwback-again-sorry-missingsummer-palmtrees-rememberwhatyouth/';

decodeBytes(url,'cp1252');
> "http://whatyouth.com/9236/roadtripppp-ðŸŒ-´ðŸš-ŒðŸ�-roadtrip-throwback-again-sorry-missingsummer-palmtrees-rememberwhatyouth/"

decodeBytes(url,'cp1251');
> "http://whatyouth.com/9236/roadtripppp-рџЊ-ґрџљ-Њрџђ-roadtrip-throwback-again-sorry-missingsummer-palmtrees-rememberwhatyouth/"
```